# ItemSliding is not working with button

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, ionic3

Can you tell me why I cannot see `Me` button? I have used [**ItemSliding**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/ItemSliding/)

Here is the [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-dau7qx). Please see the `home` folder.

I wanted to create below kind of list:

*UI*

[image]

*.html*

```
<ion-list>
        <ion-item-sliding #item>
            <ion-item>
                <button ion-button class="buttoncls">Me</button>
                <ion-label fixed>Members</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item-options side="right">
                <button ion-button (click)="deleteMember(item)" color="danger">
            <ion-icon name="ios-trash-outline"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            </ion-item-options>
        </ion-item-sliding>
    </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `ion-item` component has predefined set of selectors that can be used to transclude inside that component. [**Git repo**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/item/item.ts#L277-L289)

```
 '<ng-content select="[item-start],[item-left],ion-checkbox:not([item-end]):not([item-right])"></ng-content>' +
    '<div class="item-inner">' +
      '<div class="input-wrapper">' +
        '<ng-content select="ion-label"></ng-content>' +
        '<ion-label *ngIf="_viewLabel">' +
          '<ng-content></ng-content>' +
        '</ion-label>' +
        '<ng-content select="ion-select,ion-input,ion-textarea,ion-datetime,ion-range,[item-content]"></ng-content>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<ng-content select="[item-end],[item-right],ion-radio,ion-toggle"></ng-content>' +
      '<ion-reorder *ngIf="_hasReorder"></ion-reorder>' +
    '</div>' +
'<div class="button-effect"></div>',
```

So just add for example `item-start` attribute like

```
<button ion-button item-start class="buttoncls">Me</button>
```

and look at **[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-uagtys?file=pages/home/home.html)**

`item-right` will look like [**Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-g6b7mh?file=pages/home/home.html)

Comment: better to use `item-end` instead of `item-right` though

Comment: Oh.. Super. Thank you so much :)